# Laravel validation for exists except zero not nullable

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In categories table I have the following columns
id, parent_id, title

Now, parent_id is the parent category for sub-category, but for the root/primary categories parent_id is 0 because they have no parent!

```
<?php
'parent_id'=>'required|exists:categories,id|nullable' 
// wont work, because parent_id = 0
```

I used also [sometimes] with no luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is within `exists`. From Laravel 5.8 [exists' docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists)

> The field under validation must exist on a given database table

Applied to your case: you are requesting that the field under validation must have a value that **matches an existing id in categories table** and you're asserting

> for the root/primary categories parent_id is 0 because they have no parent

and if they have no parent **their `parent_id` won't match any `id`** in categories table.

Note also that `required` and `nullable` shouldn't be on the same validation field: from [required rule's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required)

> The field under validation must be present in the input data and not
>   empty. A field is considered "empty" if one of the following
>   conditions are true:
>
> - The value is null.
> - ...

and from [nullable rule's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-nullable)

> The field under validation may be null.

So, you are requesting that the field is not empty, but you are allowing `null` value, that's denied from `required` validation rule.

At the end, to solve your problem you have to do:

```php
[
    'parent_id' => 'exists:categories,id|nullable'
]
```

and set `NULL` on root categories, or use

```php
[
    'parent_id' => 'required'
]
```

and manually check that `parent_id` exists in your database except for root categories that will have `0`

**Side note**:
To be sure that you're inserting existing ids in your `parent_id` field, I would suggest you to add a foreign key constraint and set `NULL` on root categories:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');

    // other definitions...

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();

    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
});
```

Comment: @Matteo_Meil, thanks for your idea, I am putting all categories in select/option menu tag, in this case 0 means primary/root category. I can not use null. btw, I wont recommend using null in db.

Comment: Laravel has `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware so, you can use `<option value="">Root category</option>` to target a null value in `select`. Btw, if you don't want to use `NULL` you may not be able to use `exists` validation rule as per motivations I wrote in the answer